# Find the range of: $y=\sqrt{\sin(\log_e\frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1})}+\sqrt{\cos(\log_e\frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1})}$

Tags: functions

Find the range of:
$$y=\sqrt{\sin(\log_e\frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1})}+\sqrt{\cos(\log_e\frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1})}$$

What I tried:

Let:$$\log_e\frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1}=X,$$
then $$y=\sqrt {\sin X}+\sqrt{\cos X}$$
$$y_{max}at X=\pi/4$$

The rest is too complicated. I am stuck up.

Can someone please give a analytical solution.

Even [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D%E2%88%9A%28sin%28log%28%28x%5E2%2Be%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29%29%29%2B%E2%88%9A%28cos%28log%28%28x%5E2%2Be%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29%29%29) doesn't help.

Comment: Big hint:  $\dfrac{x^2+e}{x^2+1} = 1  + \frac{e-1}{x^2+1}$.  What can you say about the range of this function?    Once you've worked that out work out the range of $X=\log \dfrac{x^2+e}{x^2+1}$ and then work out the range of $y=\sqrt{\sin X} + \sqrt{\cos X}$.

Comment: @Tim: It is a good hint. By the way, I paid attention to your comment after I posted my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402797/range-of-sqrt-sin-cos-x-sqrt-cos-sin-x/402913#402913). First, we study the expression

$$ \frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1}=1+\frac{e-1}{x^2+1} \longrightarrow_{|x|\to\infty} 1,  $$

which implies $ y(x)\longrightarrow_{|x|\to \infty} 0 $. To find the maximum of the function $y(x)$, Let's study the function

$$ h(t)=\sqrt{\sin(t)}+\sqrt{\cos(t)}.  $$

The maximum of the above function is attained at $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$ which can proved using derivative test. So, this implies our function attains its max when

$$ \ln\left( \frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1} \right)=\frac{\pi}{4} \implies x=0.6632987771, -0.6632987771. $$

Plugging back in the function y(x) gives the max which is $y=1.681792830$. So the range is

$$ 1 < y \leq 1.681792830.$$

**Note:** You can solve $ \ln\left( \frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1} \right)=\frac{\pi}{4} $ easily as,

$$ \ln\left( \frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1} \right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\implies \frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1} =e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\implies x^2+e= e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}x^2+ e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\dots.$$

I think you can finish it.

[image]

Comment: I have the answer as $R_f=(1,2^{3/4}]$

Comment: 1.681792830~$2^{3/4}$

Comment: @MathGeek: See the note. You can get the exact value for $x$, where the function achieves its max, then substitute in the $y(x)$.

Comment: @MathGeek: Yes, that's the range. It is a typo.

Comment: You are saying $0<y≤2^{3/4}$.
But the answer is $y=(1,2^{3/4}]$

Comment: @MathGeek: It is a typo. I already corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. and from where did you made the graph?

Comment: @MathGeek: I used Maple 17. You can use Maple or Mathematica, both will give you the same answer, I believe.

Comment: @MathGeek: You are welcome. Glad to assist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8946/discussion-between-mathgeek-and-mhenni-benghorbal)

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x)=\frac{x^2+e}{x^2+1} \to 1<f(x)\le e \to 0<X\le 1$

$y^2=sinX+cosX+\sqrt{2sin2X}=\sqrt{2}\left(sin(X+\dfrac{\pi}{4})+\sqrt{sin2X}\right)$

when $0<X<\dfrac{\pi}{4}$,$sin2X$ and $sin(X+\dfrac{\pi}{4})$ are mono increasing,$\to y^2>1 \to y>1$

I left another part for you to discuss and you should be able to find out the range now.