# Maximizing sum of strictly non-negative functions?

Tags: optimization

In an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402797/range-of-sqrt-sin-cos-x-sqrt-cos-sin-x/402913#402913), it was stated that if a function is the sum of two functions $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, and ${(\forall{x})(g(x)\ge0)}$ and $(\forall{x})(h(x)\ge0)$, the relative maxima of $f(x)$ can be found by finding the relative maxima of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Intuitively I can somewhat grasp why this is the case, but analytically, what is the explanation for why this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not true, if I understand correctly.

For example, $[1+\sin(x)]+[1+\cos(x)]$ is a sum of two positive functions with maxima at $0,\pi/2$ (plus shifts) respectively where the whole function takes the value $3$.

However, at $x=\pi/4$ we get $1+\sqrt 2/2+1+\sqrt 2/2=2+\sqrt 2> 3$.

Draw the graph to check it out.

---

Looking at the other question quickly, it's possible that what you're interested in is the special case where $g,h$ have the *same sign for their slopes at all points*.

In this case, it is  true (at least for nice differentiable  functions) because of the following reasoning: let $x$ be not a maximum of $g,h$. Then both $g,h$ must increase away from $x$ in at least one direction, and that must be the same direction. Therefore $g+h$ increases in that direction too.

Note that the $g,h>0$ thing doesn't really tell you anything since you can always shift the whole graph up by a constant and smoothly kill away behaviour at infinity.